# Как из textarea принять данные в таблицу

Tags: javascript, json

Есть текстовое поле на странице, нужно его заполнять в формате:

```
[{
    id: "1",
    name: "Ivan",
    age: 25,
    friends: 5
},
{
    id: "2",
    name: "Maria",
    age: 23,
    friends: 10
},
{
    id: "3",
    name: "Alex",
    age: 47,
    friends: 3
},
{
    id: "4",
    name: "James",
    age: 34,
    friends: 12
}];
```

Все это переменная `data`. И этими значениями мы должны заполнить динамически создающуюся таблицу. Если переменную `data` просто прописывать в коде, к примеру

```
var data = [{...},{...},{...}];
```

то все работает хорошо. Но вот как сделать, чтобы по кнопке, когда уже значения введены в поле, все закидывалось в таблицу?

Comment: Перевести строку в объект

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, вы получили строку из поля и записали ее в переменную `strArea`

```
var strArea = '[{id:"1",name:"Ivan",age:25,friends:5},{id:"2",name:"Maria",age:23,friends:10},{id:"3",name:"Alex",age:47,friends:3},{id:"4",name:"James",age:34,friends:12}];'
```

Получить из этой строки `data`, можно, воспользовавшись `eval`:

```
var data = eval(strArea);
```

Answer (score 0):

Парсим с помощью `JSON.parse` (предварительно сделав "правильный" json) и в цикле загоняем в таблицу:

```js
var data = '[{id:"1",name:"Ivan",age:25,friends:5},{id:"2",name:"Maria",age:23,friends:10},{id:"3",name:"Alex",age:47,friends:3},{id:"4",name:"James",age:34,friends:12}]';

$('body').on('click', 'button', function() {
  var realJSON = data.replace(/([\w]+):/g, '"$1":');
  var dataObj = JSON.parse(realJSON);
  for(var i = 0; i < dataObj.length; i++) {
    var row = '<tr><td>' + dataObj[i].id + '</td><td>' + dataObj[i].name + '</td><td>' + dataObj[i].age + '</td><td>' + dataObj[i].friends + '</td></tr>';
    $('table').append(row);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Жми</button>
<table border="1" rules="all"></table>
```